# rsyslogd uses 435M of swap memory right after restart

Tags: linux, centos, rsyslog, swap

I have Centos 7

```
    # cat /etc/centos-release
    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

fresh rsyslogd

```
    # rsyslogd -version
    rsyslogd 8.36.0, compiled with:
```

enough free memory

```
    # free
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:       32741276    12244672     4931760      330064    15564844    19239180
```

But **rsyslogd** always uses about 430M of swap space, according to **smem**. I don't understand, why.

Can you give me some advice how to limit it's memory consumption and how to force it to use RAM instead of swap.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem, you are not under memory pressure. Note the 4 GB free and 14 GB of caches that could easily be dropped.

The purpose of swap, aka paging, space is to provide a way to reclaim anonymous pages. Which it will do even if there is memory available. An argument explaining this: [In defence of swap: common misconceptions](https://chrisdown.name/2018/01/02/in-defence-of-swap.html). And a Red Hat blog explaining some of their guidance: [Do we really need swap on modern systems?](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/do-we-really-need-swap-modern-systems)

---

More useful would be to [apply a performance profile, such as with tuned](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-tuned#installation-and-usage). Some of the profiles alter swappiness, but there is a lot more to performance than that.

Answer (score -1):

Check your swappiness kernel parameter.
https://linuxhint.com/understanding_vm_swappiness/